# E0289 отсутствуют экземпляры конструктора "Student::Student"

Tags: c++, ооп, конструктор

5 ошибок `E0289`: отсутствуют экземпляры конструктора `Student::Student`, соответствующие списку аргументов, строки 37-41.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

struct Student {
    string name;
    string group;
    int grades[5];
    double average;

    // Конструктор для вычисления среднего балла при создании объекта
    Student(string name, string group, int grades[]) {
        this->name = name;
        this->group = group;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            this->grades[i] = grades[i];
        }
        this->average = accumulate(grades, grades + 5, 0.0) / 5;
    }

    // Оператор для сравнения студентов по среднему баллу
    bool operator<(const Student& other) const {
        return average < other.average;
    }
};

int main() {
    const int n = 5;
    Student students[n] = 
    {
        Student("Ivanov I.I.", "group1", {5, 4, 5, 4, 5}),
        Student("Petrov P.P.", "group2", {4, 4, 4, 5, 5}),
        Student("Sidorov S.S.", "group1", {3, 4, 3, 4, 4}),
        Student("Kuznetsov K.K.", "group2", {5, 5, 5, 5, 5}),
        Student("Smirnov S.S.", "group1", {4, 4, 4, 4, 4})
    };

    // Сортировка студентов по среднему баллу
    sort(students, students + n);

    // Вывод фамилий и номеров групп студентов с оценками 4 и 5
    bool found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        bool has_good_grades = all_of(students[i].grades, students[i].grades + 5, [](int grade) { return grade >= 4; });
        if (has_good_grades) {
            cout << students[i].name << " " << students[i].group << endl;
            found = true;
        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        cout << "No students with good grades found." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Но они и в самом деле отсутствуют! Вы передаете третьим аргументом совсем не указатель на 'ште'? который прописан в `Student(string name, string group, int grades[])`...

Comment: Как мне это исправить?

Comment: `Student(std::string name, std::string group, std::vector<int> grades)`

Comment: Ну... Написать конструктор с `initializer_list`. Создавать и передавать массив. Воспользоваться такими вещами, как `array` или `vector`. Вариантов много, но вот какой выбрать конкретно вам?...

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, чтоб не переписывать много:

```
Student(string name, string group, const array<int,5>& grades) {
    this->name = name;
    this->group = group;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        this->grades[i] = grades[i];
    }
    this->average = accumulate(this->grades, this->grades + 5, 0.0) / 5;
}
```

У вас, кстати, в строке

```
    this->average = accumulate(grades, grades + 5, 0.0) / 5;
```

пропущены `this->`, а в данном случае это важно!

Кстати, у вас нигде кроме конструктора оценки не используются, так зачем их вообще хранить? Вычислили среднее прямо для входных данных и хватит...